# Gizmo not with active / selected object

Tags: modeling

I don't know what I have change to make it do this, but whenever I move an object, the gizmo stays in one spot and I keep having to <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>S</kbd> *Cursor to Selected* or *Cursor to Active*, to get it where I need it.

How do I get it to stay with the selected object?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your *Transform Pivot Point* panel, maybe you've selected the *3D Cursor* option, in that case the gizmo will stick to the 3D cursor, switch to *Median Point* for example:

[image]

Comment: That was it. Thanks